# Angular 2 data not binding to <table>

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding, html-table

I was trying to bind simple JSON data to `<table>`. But, my html page is showing empty data, but the row count is showing as per data. The data inside each `<tr>` is empty. Not sure what's wrong with my code.

Can someone help me if I am doing anything wrong here?

**Pay.Component.ts**

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,    
templateUrl: './pay.component.html'
})

export class PayComponent  {    

myData: any[] = [
    {
        "Col1": "120f2dcf-d4a4-4b3c-994a-e4e0c79bd642",
        "Col2": "2017-03-27T00:00:00-07:00",
        "Col3": "Testing1"            
    },
    {
        "Col1": "320f2dcf-d4a4-4b3c-994a-e4e0c79bd642",
        "Col2": "2018-03-27T00:00:00-07:00",
        "Col3": "Testing2"            
    }]
}
```

**pay.component.html**

```
<div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                                <th>Col3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor='let pay of myData'>
                                <td>{{ pay.col1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ pay.col2 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ pay.col3 }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Not sure what's going wrong with code.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I found the issue as i was using lower case when the data was binding to the table.

Fixed the issue after changing to UPPER Case {{ pay.Col1 }}